# Android cannot check json success and error response

Tags: android, json

I am struggling with one situation. I am returning some json data from PHP server my code is as follows,

PHP API code:

```
if ($user != false) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT stock_name,stock_location FROM btrack_stock WHERE user_id= '$user_id'") or die(mysql_error());
        $rows = array();
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($count > 0){
            while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
              $rows[] = $r;
            }
            echo json_encode(array('usertransaction' => $rows));  
        }else{
            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "You do not have any transaction so far. ";
            echo json_encode($response); 
        }
    }
```

On android side, I use a class that extends AsyncTask and on my onPostExecute I use:

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {

            if(json.getString("error_msg") != null){
                String err = json.getString("error_msg");
                stock_error.setText(err);
                stock_error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }else{
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Well actually, I wanted to display error message that is returned from PHP server and display all the data if I got success message (here I am showing a Toast). 
My question is how can we display error message if json returns error message and display success if json does not return error message.

*** My code works fine if I get error_msg as json response but if I return other data the app stuck in process dialog with a warning in LogCat as " There is no value for error_msg".

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use `if(json.has("error_msg")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 if json.isNull("error_msg") {
       do_something()
 }
 else {
    json.getString("error_msg");
    do_something_else()
 }
```